# How long does an Android Market 503 response take to reset?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

The [licensing docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) say:

> The licensing server applies general request limits to guard against
>   overuse of resources that could result in denial of service. When an
>   application exceeds the request limit, the licensing server returns a
>   503 response, which gets passed through to your application as a
>   general server error. This means that no license response will be
>   available to the user until the limit is reset, which can affect the
>   user for an indefinite period.

How long is this "indefinite period"? I suspect this may be the reason some of my users are getting false failures, and I need to know if I can expect it to start working anytime soon, or if I have to find some other way of enabling the app for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotas aren't published, and are subject to change.

Generally speaking, the guidelines is: Do not check licensing status more frequently than once per application launch. (A common error is checking licensing status every time an activity starts -- which will cause a licensing check every time the screen is rotated.)

More generally, we strongly encourage people to use ServerManagedPolicy, which caches license responses for a period of time. Not only does this guard against server errors and most quota issues, it also keeps your users happy when they're on an airplane or in an area of weak cell reception.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of these guidelines, and have implemented my license checking code accordingly, but I am desperately trying to figure out why some of my users are getting incorrect Failure responses. I wondered if the 503 limit could be an explanation and was just wondering how long I'd have to wait before I could eliminate that possibility.